# How to set slice interface values with reflection

Tags: go

I would like to build a function that takes a generic pointer array and fill that list based on mongo results.

I don't know how to set the value I got from mongo into my pointer array. In the below attempt, program panics with following error : `reflect.Set: value of type []interface {} is not assignable to type []Person`

When I print total / documents found, it corresponds to what I am expecting. So I think question is about reflection.

```
func getListWithCount(ctx context.Context, receiver interface{}) (int, error) {
    //my mongo query here
    var mongoResp struct {
        Total     int         `bson:"total"`
        Documents interface{} `bson:"documents"`
    }
    if err := cursor.Decode(&mongoResp); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    receiverValue := reflect.ValueOf(receiver)
    docs := []interface{}(mongoResp.Documents.(primitive.A))
    receiverValue.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(docs))

    return mongoResp.Total, nil 
}

type Person struct {
    Name string `bson:"name"`
}

func main() {
    var persons []Person
    count, err := getListWithCount(context.Background(), &persons)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(count)
    fmt.Println(persons)
}
```

Comment: I'm not a mongo user at all, but given that you are setting the passed in pointer as the `Documents` value, I would assume that `cursor.Decode` will decode the result into that pointer. Have you tried the following https://play.golang.org/p/EoTuBlZ5w_e?

Comment: it prints an empty array, where as a `fmt.Println(mongoResp.Documents)` inside `getListWithCount` prints an actual list

Comment: mongo will decode into the struct passed. `Documents` is an interface type. Passing an initial value does not change its signature. Hence why I may need reflection.

Comment: Understood, so the `Documents: receiver,` line is completely pointless, you'd get the same result even if you dropped that line.

Comment: Correct, I'll edit the post to trim unecessary lines

Comment: Unfortunately no, the struct passed in the cursor has a field `Documents interface{}` not a defined type.

I need to convert results from []interface{} to []myType{}

Comment: yes, mongoresp is the document queried. It contains a generic array and a count. In the example I'd like to get Persons, but I'd like to eventually be able to query other types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to decode first into [`bson.RawValue`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#RawValue) and then [`Unmarshal`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#RawValue.Unmarshal) it into the `receiver`.

```golang
func getListWithCount(ctx context.Context, receiver interface{}) (int, error) {
    //my mongo query here
    var mongoResp struct {
        Total     int           `bson:"total"`
        Documents bson.RawValue `bson:"documents"`
    }
    if err := cursor.Decode(&mongoResp); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    if err := mongoResp.Documents.Unmarshal(receiver); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return mongoResp.Total, nil 
}
```

---

You can also implement it as a custom [`bson.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#Unmarshaler).

```golang
type MongoResp struct {
    Total     int         `bson:"total"`
    Documents interface{} `bson:"documents"`
}

func (r *MongoResp) UnmarshalBSON(data []byte) error {
    var temp struct {
        Total     int           `bson:"total"`
        Documents bson.RawValue `bson:"documents"`
    }
    if err := bson.Unmarshal(data, &temp); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    r.Total = temp.Total
    return temp.Documents.Unmarshal(r.Documents)
}
```

With that you would use it in the function like so:

```golang
func getListWithCount(ctx context.Context, receiver interface{}) (int, error) {
    //my mongo query here
    mongoResp := MongoResp{Documents: receiver}
    if err := cursor.Decode(&mongoResp); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return mongoResp.Total, nil 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically create a struct type that matches the queried document.  See commentary below for details.

```
func getListWithCount(receiver interface{}) (int, error) {
    dst := reflect.ValueOf(receiver).Elem()

    //  Your mongo query here

    // Create a struct type that matches the document.
    doct := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
        reflect.StructField{Name: "Total", Type: reflect.TypeOf(0), Tag: `bson:"total"`},
        reflect.StructField{Name: "Documents", Type: dst.Type(), Tag: `bson:"documents"`},
    })

    // Decode to a value of the type.
    docp := reflect.New(doct)
    if err := cursor.Decode(docp.Interface()); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    docv := docp.Elem()

    // Copy the Documents field to *receiver.
    dst.Set(docv.Field(1))

    // Return the total
    return docv.Field(0).Interface().(int), nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks, even though it adresses the reflection question I had, I think I was mistaken. The bson.RawValue from @mkopriva seems to handle properly what I need without too much complication.

Answer (score -1):

there is no need to use reflect here, you can decode it directly to your Person slices

```golang
func getPersons(ctx context.Context, coll *mongo.Collection, results interface{}) error {
    cur, err := coll.Find(ctx, bson.D{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = cur.All(ctx, results)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

and the `len` is the count of the results.

```golang
err = getPersons(ctx, coll, &persons)
require.NoError(t, err)
t.Logf("Got %d persons: %v", len(persons), persons)
```

see https://gist.github.com/xingyongtao/459f92490bdcbf7d5afe9f5d1ae6c04a

Comment: In my case, total is the amount of documents before pagination (offset / limit). Hence I can't decode with cursor.All

Comment: maybe you should use `count` for `total`